# Hibernate. Getting all rows return nullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, model-view-controller

I'm trying to get all rows from "Location" table. But my DAO method always return NullPointerException. I don't know why does it happens. I have tried hql, criteria etc., but result was the same.

Controller

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;
private FuturePlanService futurePlanService;
private LocationService locationService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}/addPlan", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView addFuturePlan(@PathVariable int id){
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("add_future");
    User user = userService.findById(id);
    FuturePlan futurePlan = new FuturePlan();
    List<Location> locations = locationService.getAll();

    modelAndView.addObject("ownerUser", user);
    modelAndView.addObject("future", futurePlan);
    modelAndView.addObject("locations", locations);

    return modelAndView;
}
```

Location Dao

```
@Repository
public class LocationDaoImpl implements LocationDao {

@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Override
public Location findLocation(int id) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Location location = (Location) session.get(Location.class, id);
    session.close();
    return location;
}

@Override
public Location findLocation(String name) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Location.class);
    cr.add(Restrictions.eq("lName", name));
    cr.setMaxResults(1);
    Location location = (Location) cr.uniqueResult();
    session.close();
    return location;
}

@Override
public List<Location> getAll() {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    List<Location> list = session.createQuery("from Location").list();
    session.close();
    return list;
}
```

}

Location Entity

```
@Entity
public class Location {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int lId;
private String lName;

public Location() {
    super();
}

public Location(int lId, String lName) {
    super();
    this.lId = lId;
    this.lName = lName;
}

public int getlId() {
    return lId;
}

public void setlId(int lId) {
    this.lId = lId;
}

public String getlName() {
    return lName;
}

public void setlName(String lName) {
    this.lName = lName;
}
```

HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException. 
In this line List locations = locationService.getAll();. In Controller.

If u need more files, just tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Autowired` only applys to the immediate class member. Add it to `locationService`

```
@Autowired
private LocationService locationService;
```

Do the same for `futurePlanService` if it features in your future plans ;)

Comment: Thx Reimeus! I thought i can use multiple services under one annotation.
Your solution solved my problem.